# gitweb and per project http authentication

Tags: git, apache, gitweb

I have successfully set up gitweb on an apache vHost accessable for all authenticated users.

The server itself provides several git repositories via https and has per user/group access to those projects. For example test1.git is only readable/writable by group test1 and test2.git is only readable/writable by group test2.

Now I also want only those groups to see their corresponding git repositories in the gitweb interface. Is it possible to have those granular access rights for gitweb?

If not, is there a light-weight web gui for git, that can handle basic http authentication per project (and possibly ldap authentication for later)?

**Edit**
Just to make things clearer (as there seems some confusion from the comments):
Example:

- There are 10 repositories (test1, test2, ... test10)
- user **lockdoc** is in group **test1** and **test3**
- Once authenticated over http with username **lockdoc** and his/her password, this user can only see git projects **test1** and **test3** and cannot browse/see any other projects
- No need for writing (pushing) over the webinterface, as this is already implemented

Comment: Do you want to have a simple, *read only* view of your repositories (in this case GitWeb is suitable) or do you want to manage the repositories (in that case gitolite as answered by @VonC is an option)?

Comment: By the way, I think this question is better suited in the [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) Stack.

Comment: You could try matching different URLs in different `<Location>` or `<LocationMatch>` sections requiring different authentication settings (file, method, ...).

Comment: I confirm, based on your edit, that gitolite is the right tool for the job. I have edited my answer with more details.

Answer (score 4):

No GUI, but I would recommend using [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) for this kind of fine-grained [authorization](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html).

See this [httpd.conf for LDAP and gitolite access](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49-L64):

- you can define a gitweb access, which in turn will call gitolite, see this [gitweb.conf.pl](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl) script
- you can define an [https acces](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L107-L112)s which will also call gitolite (in order to allow or deny access, depending on your id)

The https config would look like this:

```
ScriptAlias /hgit/ @H@/sbin/gitolite-shell/
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "@H@/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
<Location /hgit>
   ...
</Location>
```

In both case, you can protect those http addresses with LDAP-based authentication:

```
AuthName "LDAP authentication for ITSVC Smart HTTP Git repositories"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider myldap companyldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative Off
Require valid-user
```

And you will register your users/groups/repos in the [`gitolite.conf` configuration file](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/admin.html#conf) associated with gitolite.

```
@lockdoc_repos           =   test1 test3 # group of repo

repo @lockdoc_repos
    R                    = lockdoc # read-only access for lockdoc
    R                    = gitweb daemon # can be browsed
```

See "[testing/info/refs not found in gitolite after removing R @all rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14012254/6309)" for more on how to allow browsing for a repo, by [sitaram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925116/sitaram) ([Sitaram Chamarty](https://plus.google.com/u/0/115609618223925128756/posts)), creator of gitolite himself.